# How to float menu in bootstrap btn-group to the left?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="pull-right">

 <div class="btn-group pull-left">
  <div class="btn-group">
   <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">some link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some link 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

And I would like to have something like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the dropdown appear to the right alignment , you have to simply assign the pullright to the dropdown-menu :

Jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/eerLr/)

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
   <li><a href="#">some link 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

In your presented code the pull-left class assigned to the button group will not really pull it to left as the parent div is using pull-right class . If you want to control the button group alignment and its position .You can do the following :
**Dont use** the  `div class="btn-group"` multiple times

Check jsfiddle with your presented code(cleaned up a bit) [Demo with button](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/xvbGz/)
Assign class left inplace of class pull-left , this way :

```
 <div class="btn-group left"> <!-- I have assigned a new class to it i.e left -->
```

Than write css to position :

```
.btn-group.left{
   bottom: 15px;
   position: relative;
   top: 15px;
   right:20px;
  }
```

Comment: @derfder check the jsfiddle and let me know if you face any issue . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in the `dropdown-menu` class change `left: 0` to `right: 0`

Comment: I have upgraded my code. I have missed something. Now, it is complete. I am using `pull-right` maybe that is the praoblem. Btw. `right: 0` is not working ;(